# Difference between hex array and hex literal

Tags: c, arrays

I'm not even 100% sure I labeled the title correctly but here goes. I'm attempting to use [these LED's](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/2343/APA102C.pdf). I have to write to it through a SPI bus which is all working fine however there is something weird going on and I'm not sure why.

I'm wanting to make the LED "pulse". If I do this it works fine:

```
quadrantFrame_1[0] = 0xe9;
quadrantFrame_1[1] = 228;
Update_SPI();

CyDelay(delay + 10);

quadrantFrame_1[0] = 0xe8;
quadrantFrame_1[1] = 228;
Update_SPI();

CyDelay(delay + 10);

quadrantFrame_1[0] = 0xe7;
quadrantFrame_1[1] = 228;
Update_SPI();

CyDelay(delay + 10);

quadrantFrame_1[0] = 0xe6;
quadrantFrame_1[1] = 218;
Update_SPI();

CyDelay(delay + 10);

quadrantFrame_1[0] = 0xe5;
quadrantFrame_1[1] = 208;
Update_SPI();

CyDelay(delay + 10);

quadrantFrame_1[0] = 0xe4;
quadrantFrame_1[1] = 198;
Update_SPI();

CyDelay(delay + 10);

quadrantFrame_1[0] = 0xe3;
quadrantFrame_1[1] = 188;
Update_SPI();

CyDelay(delay + 10);

quadrantFrame_1[0] = 0xe2;
quadrantFrame_1[1] = 178;
Update_SPI();

CyDelay(delay + 10);

quadrantFrame_1[0] = 0xe1;
quadrantFrame_1[1] = 168;
Update_SPI();

CyDelay(delay + 10);

quadrantFrame_1[0] = 0xe0;
quadrantFrame_1[1] = 158;
Update_SPI();

CyDelay(delay + 10);

quadrantFrame_1[0] = 0xe1;
quadrantFrame_1[1] = 168;
Update_SPI();

CyDelay(delay + 10);

quadrantFrame_1[0] = 0xe2;
quadrantFrame_1[1] = 178;
Update_SPI();

CyDelay(delay + 10);

quadrantFrame_1[0] = 0xe3;
quadrantFrame_1[1] = 188;
Update_SPI();

CyDelay(delay + 10);

quadrantFrame_1[0] = 0xe4;
quadrantFrame_1[1] = 198;
Update_SPI();

CyDelay(delay);

quadrantFrame_1[0] = 0xe5;
quadrantFrame_1[1] = 208;
Update_SPI();

CyDelay(delay);

quadrantFrame_1[0] = 0xe6;
quadrantFrame_1[1] = 218;
Update_SPI();

CyDelay(delay);

quadrantFrame_1[0] = 0xe7;
quadrantFrame_1[1] = 228;
Update_SPI();

CyDelay(delay);

quadrantFrame_1[0] = 0xe8;
quadrantFrame_1[1] = 238;
Update_SPI();

CyDelay(delay);

quadrantFrame_1[0] = 0xe9;
quadrantFrame_1[1] = 238;
Update_SPI();
```

In which `quadrantFrame_1[0]` is the brightness and `quadrantFrame_1[1]` is the blue value (you don't need to worry about that). So if I do the above code it works perfectly...meaning the brightness gradually goes down then back up.

I'm trying to clean that up by using a couple of `for` loops that looks like this:

```
unsigned char values[10] = {0xe0, 0xe1, 0xe2, 0xe3, 0xe4, 0xe5, 0xe6, 0xe7, 0xe8, 0xe9};

for (i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    quadrantFrame_1[0] = values[i];
    quadrantFrame_1[1] = 228;
    Update_SPI();

    CyDelay(delay + 10);
}

for (i = 9; i >= 0; i++) {
    quadrantFrame_1[0] = values[i];
    quadrantFrame_1[1] = 228;
    Update_SPI();

    CyDelay(delay + 10);
}
```

So, with this it should gradually get brighter then dimmer all while staying the same color...however, if I do the above it goes absolutely crazy. The colors start changing to blue/violet/red/etc. and the brightness is all over the place.

The only difference I can see is that in the working solution I set the value explicitly: `quadrantFrame_1[0] = 0xe9;`. Then in the non working solution I attempt to set it from an array: `quadrantFrame_1[0] = values[i];`.

I don't understand why the array attempt wouldn't work?

Per the data sheet I know that my bits need to be correct: 
[image]

Which they should be and are in the first example. I'm not sure if this is working because I set the value explicitly, then the second example doesn't work because they are being cast as `unsigned char` values in the array...maybe?

Comment: No, I don't think that that is the reason. Don't know much about your HW but the two code versions do not look like they are doing the same thing. The first version sets variable values to both `quadrantFrame_1[0]` and `quadrantFrame_1[1]` whereas the second version keeps `quadrantFrame_1[1]` constant.

Comment: @kaylum that's just the color value and doesn't have any effect on the brightness. Turns out my second for loop had a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is a typo in the second loop `for (i = 9; i >= 0; i++) {`, where you should have written `i--` instead of `i++`.

Comment: my god I need sleep. Wish I could buy you a beer sir.

Comment: I would prefer the beer over the reputation :-)

Comment: smh this was embarrassing, will accept as soon as possible :)

Comment: note that `i` should have a signed type too (for unsigned, `i >= 0` is always true). I'd recommend using the loop counter scoped to the loop, i.e. `for (int i = 9;` ...